# Removing every 5th char in a string and return new String

Tags: java, string, char, stringbuffer

I'm trying to eliminate every 5th character of a string, unless the character is a space or a dot, and return the new string.

At the minute I can only seem to return the characters at every fifth occurrence but not manipulate them and return the new string.

Example
Original String: "James scored 1 goal. His team won."

New String: "Jame scoed 1 goal! His team won!"

I've tried to use a for loop with a selection statement but can't seem to manipulate correctly and then return the full new string.

```
public class TextProcessorTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sentence = "James scored 1 goal. His team won.";
        String newSentence;
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        int len = sentence.length();

        for(int i=4;i<len;i=i+5){
            char c = sentence.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(c);

            if(c == ' '){
                buff.append(c);
            }else if(c == '.'){
                buff.append(c);
            }else{
                buff.append("");
            }
        }

        newSentence = buff.toString();
        System.out.println(newSentence);
    }
}
```

Expected result is:
"Jame scoed 1 goal! His team won!"

Actual result is: 
"sr .  . "

Comment: You're only *adding* every fifth character, and then only if it is a space or a period.

Comment: I'm sure I saw today a similar question, with almost the same code and the use of a StringBuffer. Why StringBuffer? Is it a school assighment?

Comment: yeah, it's a question on a past exam paper in preparation for an exam. Beginner Java. Needs to be done using the basic concepts and syntax.

Comment: I've tried iterating through the string and using nested selection statements too but can't figure it out. Couldn't find any questions that assisted, any similar one's I didn't understand!

Comment: *basic concepts* fine, but why StringBuffer. Is this your idea?

Comment: No, it's what we've been asked to use. Don't ask me why though. I've figured out what I need using it, but will definitely read up on StringBuilder

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just ignore every 5th character and build new string using `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String remove(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' || str.charAt(i - 1) == '.' || i % 5 != 0)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i - 1));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

#### StringBuilder vs StringBuffer

- `StringBuffer` use in concurrent modification. This is **thread-safe**.
- `StringBuilder` use in all not concurrent modifications.

Comment: I didn't use the same answer but the logic helped me try something different. New to Java so still trying to get my head around the basic concepts.

Thanks for the help, really appreciate it